# lock screen by windows service

Tags: service, process, locking, window, desktop

I want to lock the screen using window service. My OS is win 7 and i know service has some rights issues and due to it i have done following experiments but none of my experiment worked.

I made a new exe file and called inside LockWorkStation. Manually it locks the screen but calling this exe from the service gives access denied.

here is caller code inside my service

```
if (CreateProcess(folder.c_str(),NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
        ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, 1000);
        DWORD exit = 100;
        GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess, &exit);

        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

To make it run i have logon my service with current windows user id and password. Still it didnt work then i have ticked allow service to interact with desktop. Using this gives success and shows no error but still screen doesnt get lock. ( I know using interaction with desktop service is insecure but i am thinking if any one has any solution regarding it?)

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing! Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't found !  But had to change the way and done something like using another agent exe that runs on the startup of windows and it used to watch registry change ...once it find the change it lock the window. On service side i was using just registry entry to write. (If you ever find a good solution than this one then kindly share here )

Comment: I think I'll end up with a similar solution of yours. Another solution would be to use some IPC like a RPC system but the registry seems a lot more easier to implement!